# Javascipt increases the 1st number found in URL instead of the image id

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields, lightbox

In short, the code below will increase the image number in the url in order to navigate to the next image:

```
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery/#image1
```

to

```
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery/#image2
```

The problem is when I have a number 'earlier on' in the url, then that number is increased instead of the image number:

```
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery-1/#image1
```

to

```
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery-2/#image1
```

**In more detail:**

I have the following code for creating a lightbox for my gallery custom post type.
In order to get the lightbox navigation to work, I need to count the total number of images on the lightbox. Everything works perfectly, when clicking next, #image1 becomes #image2.
The problem is whenever the post has a number in the slug, then that number is increased instead of the image number.

The below links will demonstrate the issue ( click on an image to open lightbox and navigate to next image)

With a number in the post title:
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery-1/

Without the number in post title:
https://bwrtsa.co.za/photos/test-gallery/

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <div class="photos-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <span class="photos-header-notice">
          Click on any image to enlarge and see the caption.
        </span>
      </div>
     
 
 <?php
$images = get_field('gallery_images');
$itotal = count($images);
$i = 0;

if( $images ): ?>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-gallery">
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?> 
    <?php $i++ ?>  

      <div class="box boxbg">
        <a href="#image<?php echo $i; ?>" class="ioverlay">
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['galleryThumb']); ?>" alt="Thumbnail of <?php echo esc_url($image['alt']); ?>" />
          <div class="text">
            <span>View</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div> <!-- BOX END -->

      <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div> <!-- END GRID -->
    

<?php
$slug = $post->post_name; 
$images = get_field('gallery_images');
$itotal = count($images); 
$i = 0; 

foreach( $images as $image ): 
$i++;
?>


  <div class="lightbox short-animate" id="image<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['galleryLarge']); ?>" alt="Image <?php echo esc_url($image['alt']); ?>" class="long-animate" />
  </div>

<?php endforeach; ?> 

<?php
global $post;
?>


<div class="short-animate" id="close-wrapper">
  <!-- <a href="/#Gallery" id="close-lightbox" class="long-animate"></a> -->
    <a href="/<?php echo $slug ?>" id="close-lightbox" class="long-animate"></a>
</div>
    
<div class="short-animate" id="next-wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="next-lightbox" class="long-animate"></a>
</div>
    
<div class="short-animate" id="prev-wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="prev-lightbox" class="long-animate"></a>
</div>


  
</div>
<?php endif; ?>


</div> <!-- CONTAINER -->
</div> <!-- MODULE -->
<?php // endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';

let link;
let imageCount = <?php echo $itotal; ?>;
let regExDigit = /\d+/;

function imageLink() {
  let regExImage = /#image\d+/;
  let image = location.href;
  link = regExImage.exec(image)[0];
  link = regExDigit.exec(link)[0];
}

let next = document.getElementById('next-lightbox');
let prev = document.getElementById('prev-lightbox');

next.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  imageLink();
  let newLink = Number(link) + 1;
  if (newLink > imageCount) newLink = 1;  
  location.href = location.href.replace(regExDigit, newLink);
});

prev.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  imageLink();
  let newLink = Number(link) - 1;
  if (newLink < 1) newLink = imageCount;
  location.href = location.href.replace(regExDigit, newLink);
});
</script>







</div><!-- entry-content -->
</article> 
<!--</div> #post-## -->
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the digit in the whole URL using `location.href = location.href.replace(regExDigit, newLink);`, you only want to replace it in the hash part of the URL (i.e. the part after the `#`)

What we can do instead is generate the new URL after we replace the number, instead of replacing the number in the current URL. This makes sure we *only* change the image number. Your new `imageLink` function will look like this (I've also removed the global variables to make the code cleaner and clearer):

```
/* 
Get the current image url, replace the number in the hash (#imageN) and return the new URL
Note the new parameter: changeBy = what to change the image number by: 1 for next, -1 for prev
*/
function imageLink(changeBy) {
  let regExDigit = /\d+/;
  var currentNum = 0;

  let currentURL = location.href;  

  var parts = currentURL.split("#");   // split URL to get main url and image hash
  var url_gallery_part = parts[0];    // e.g. http://www.example.com/photos/test-gallery-1/
  var imagehash = parts[parts.length - 1];  // e.g. image1

  // if there is a hash in the url, extract the number
  if (imagehash) currentNum = regExDigit.exec(imagehash)[0];

  // Call our function that calculates the prev/next number
  // pass in the current image number and change to change by (e.g. +1 or -1)
  newNum = getNewNum(currentNum, changeBy);

  // rebuild our full image url replacing the number with the enw number
  newImageLink = url_gallery_part + "#" + imagehash.replace(regExDigit, newNum);

  return newImageLink;
}
```

**What this does:**

1. We add a new parameter `changeBy` to tells the function what to change the image by, e.g. +1 for next, -1 for previous
2. `split` the URL into parts based on the `#` - this will give us the main url and also the hash for the image.
3. Extract the number from the image hash using your regex
4. Calculate the new number depending  on whether we want the next (+1) or previous (-1) image
5. Rebuild our full image URL and return it to our handler

We can also tidy up the code to calculate the new image number - we pass in the current image number and our changeBy parameter, and it returns the new number:

```
/* 
currentNum: the current image number
changeBy: what to change the number by, e.g. 1 for next, -1 for previous 
*/
function getNewNum(currentNum, changeBy) {
  newNum = Number(currentNum) + changeBy;  // adjust the current number
  
  // Make sure it is within the bounds of the number of images
  if (newNum > imageCount)  newNum = 1;
  else if (newNum < 1)      newNum = imageCount;

  return newNum;
}
```

The only thing to note here is that it combines the 2 separate blocks of code in your event handlers. By passing in 1 or -1, that value is added or subtracted from the current number so it works for both next *and* previous.

Now our even handlers are like this:

```
next.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // get the full URL for next image by adding 1 to the current image
  location.href = getImage(1);   
});

prev.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // get the full URL for prev image by subtracting 1 from the current image
  location.href = imageLink(-1);
});
```

**Working Example:** You can see this code working below, with a few small tweaks to use the url string that is displayed instead of the page URL (which obviously won't work here):

```js
let imageCount = 5;

// Display elements for demo only
let next = document.getElementById('next-lightbox');
let prev = document.getElementById('prev-lightbox');
let imageDisplay = document.getElementById('imageDisplay');

/* 
Get the current image url, replace the number in the hash (#imageN) and return the new 
URL
Note the new parameter: changeBy = what to change the image number by: 1 for next, -1 for prev
*/
function imageLink(changeBy) {
  let regExDigit = /\d+/;
  var currentNum = 0;

  var currentURL = imageDisplay.innerHTML;  // for demo only - use location.href
  //let currentURL = location.href;  

  // split URL to get main url and image hash
  var parts = currentURL.split("#");
  var url_gallery_part = parts[0];
  var imagehash = parts[parts.length - 1];

  // if there is a hash in the url, extract the number
  if (imagehash) currentNum = regExDigit.exec(imagehash)[0];

  // Call our function that calculates the prev/next number
  // pass in the current image number and chage t ochange by (e.g. +1 or -1)
  newNum = getNewNum(currentNum, changeBy);

  // rebuild our full image url replacing the number with the enw number
  newImageLink = url_gallery_part + "#" + imagehash.replace(regExDigit, newNum);

  return newImageLink;
}

/* 
currentNum: the current image number
changeBy: what to change the number by, e.g. 1 for next, -1 for previous 
*/
function getNewNum(currentNum, changeBy) {
  newNum = Number(currentNum) + changeBy; // adjust the current number
  
  // Make sure it is within the bounds of the number of images
  if (newNum > imageCount)  newNum = 1;
  else if (newNum < 1)      newNum = imageCount;
  return newNum;
}

next.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // get the full URL for next image by adding 1 to the current image
  imageDisplay.innerHTML = imageLink(1);  // for demo. replace with below
  //  location.href = imageLink(1);
});

prev.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // get the full URL for prev image by subtracting 1 from the current image
  imageDisplay.innerHTML = imageLink(-1); // for demo. replace with below
  //  location.href = imageLink(-1);
});
```

```html
<button id="next-lightbox">Next</button>
<button id="prev-lightbox">Prev</button>
<div id="imageDisplay">https://www.example.com/photos/test-gallery-1/#image1</div>
```

Comment: Than you so much for all the effort you put into your answer, it worked like a charm! Much appreciated!